# Replacing content inside of a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I replace the one content inside of textarea. I have a textarea for the user's favorite devices.

```
<textarea id="favDevices" class="t"></textarea>
```

Let's say users give this three devices:

```
Laptop
Computer
PlayStation 4
```

After submitting it (using the jquery ajax) I want to replace one of the content to  `device-VALIDATED`. So the results would be

```
Laptop-VALIDATED
Computer-VALIDATED
PlayStation 4-VALIDATED
```

I try figure out how can I do it using this code:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    f = $("#favDevices").val().split("\n")
    for(i in f){
        device = f[i];
        // function here to send data to back end
        f.replace(device, device + "-VALIDATED")
    }
})
```

Comment: *"After submitting it..."* So you're asking how to split a string into lines and add `-VALIDATED` to the end of each line, then recombine it into a single string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    const $favDevices = $("#favDevices")
    const unvalidated = $favDevices.val()
    const validated = unvalidated
                        .split("\n")
                        .map(line => `${line}-VALIDATE`)
                        .join("")
    $favDevices.val(validated)
})
```

Comment: Ah, if only line breaks were that simple, cross-browser/OS... :-)

Comment: But I want to replace those content inside of textarea to `device-VALIDATED` so the new value of `device` is `device-VALIDATED`

Comment: @JohnAlbertFlores - Then use `val(validated)` on your textarea again.

Answer (score 0):

The value from the textarea is a string. You need to split the string into lines, add `-VALIDATED` to the end of each line, then recombine it into a single string.

I usually use a regular expression like this to split into lines:

```
let lines = $("#favDevices").val().split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/);
```

Then `map` is useful for processing each line:

```
lines = lines.map(line => line + "-VALIDATED");
```

Then `join` recombines into a single string; choose your delimiter, I usually use a single `\n`.

```
const str = lines.join("\n");
```

Live Example:

```js
const str =
  $("#favDevices").val().split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/)
  .map(line => line + "-VALIDATED")
  .join("\n");
console.log(JSON.stringify(str));
```

```html
<textarea id="favDevices" class="t">Laptop
Computer
PlayStation 4</textarea>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

In a comment you've said:

> But I want to replace those content inside of textarea to `device-VALIDATED` so the new value of device is `device-VALIDATED`

You'd add a fourth step: Writing back to the `textarea`:

```
$("#favDevices").val(str);
```

Live Example:

```js
const favDevices = $("#favDevices");
const str =
  favDevices.val().split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/)
  .map(line => line + "-VALIDATED")
  .join("\n");
favDevices.val(str);
```

```html
<textarea id="favDevices" class="t">Laptop
Computer
PlayStation 4</textarea>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```